# Unauthorized Exception in OAuthPrompt in MS Teams Bot GCC High

Tags: bots, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have create a Bot using https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth/ this template.
for user Authentication I am using OAuthPromt but getting this exception

**Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'**

return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
at Dialogs/MainDialog.cs

Please help me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be Authentication Token Error i.e OAuth. Azure AAD is unable to issue a token to your bot APP registration. I would suggest you go through the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Caadv2%2Ccsharp#create-the-azure-ad-identity-provider) step by step and also make sure Bot IDs, Bot Passwords are correct.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. all information are correct.  but after adding these lines of code in startup file. getting now Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadGateway' exception. `string uri = "https://apiGCCH.botframework.azure.us";
            MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(uri);
            OAuthClientConfig.OAuthEndpoint = uri;`

Comment: @Vivek - Have you updated your redirect URL for app registration from Azure to https://tokengcch.botframework.azure.us/.auth/web/redirect.

Comment: yes already updated redirect URL.

Comment: @Vivek - Could you please refer below document and validate your steps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/how-to-deploy-gov-cloud-high?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp